# Is it okay to assign values to variables inside template part in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I am printing some data on some condition by looping It is working fine but i feel like my approach is not correct as i am doing calculation based work inside the script tag (javascript portion below )

My for loop

```
<div v-for="row in cars.honda" v-if="cars.id == row.car_id" >
                    **<span v-show="txt=='show'">{{ cars.id == row.car_id?txt="sizes":txt="showerror"}}</span>**
                    
                    <p v-if="cars.id == row.car_id" >
                        {{ row.car_name}}

                    </p>
                </div>
```

Is it okay or good practice to assign value to txt variable inside  tag as i am unable to do the same thing when I create a  function in script tag It doesnt works that way as the txt variable value is not updated

Answer (score 1):

No, it not recommended even the first line of code is not recommended. Using `v-for` and `v-if` together is not a good idea. You can read more about it [vuejs doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for)

Assigning a new txt variable, that also you should generally avoid, it will hard to track if your template have more code.

Here is sample you can do it in a simple way.

```
<div v-for="row in cars.honda" :key="row.id">
  <div v-if="cars.id == row.car_id">
     <span v-if="somecondition">Show Valid Data</span>
     <span v-else>Show Error</span>
      <p>
          {{ row.car_name}}
      </p>
  </div>     
</div>
```

Generally its good practice to avoid multiple computation in the template, template are mean to be represent the data with help of directive like `v-for` `v-if` etc. They are not much responsible for computation of logic. Also use `:key` with `v-for` for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why we don't use ternary operations like you have used is because it's a recipe for bugs. Everything inside the Double brackets "{{ }}" is escaped which means if you include any html tags they would be removed. Your example should be working fine but it's best practice to only stick with v-if & v-else

```
<span v-if="somethingIsTrue">{{showSomething}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you although you could use `v-if` with `v-for`, it's not a recommended approach. Read [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for) for more.

> When used together with v-if, v-for has a higher priority than v-if. See the list rendering guide for details.

Therefore, you should always use `v-for` independently and then use `v-if` inside it to show/hide content based on some conditions.

Now coming to your question on whether it is safe to assign values in templates, **the answer is no it's not**, because that's just a bad syntax which is difficult to read. Ternary operator is **not** used to assign values like the way you have used.

###### Correct syntax for assigning using a ternary operator is:

```js
let a = b=="something" ? "Hello" : "world";
```

Which in turn should be encapsulated within a `computed` property or a `method` to be called everywhere in `vuejs`.

##### Showing a sample approach below

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    cars: {
      id: 1,
      honda: [
        {car_id: 1, car_name: "Honda City"},
        {car_id: 2, car_name: "Honda Civic"},
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isSameCar(carID){
      return this.cars.id ===carID ? true : false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="row in cars.honda" :key="row.id">
    <div v-if="isSameCar(row.car_id)">       
        <p>{{ row.car_name}}</p>
    </div> 
    <div v-else>       
        <p>Not the same car, so show error here</p>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```